# Can't Install pdfedit lubuntu 14.04 i386

Tags: lubuntu, dependencies

I tried installing `pdfedit` on my machine can't complete the installation.
The screen is giving the following infos, I could not understand. I am new a new user of Lubuntu and still feeling my way around but learning in a slow pace.

```
~$ FILE=`mktemp`; wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pdfedit/pdfedit_0.4.5-2_i386.deb -qO $FILE && sudo dpkg -i $FILE; rm $FILE
Selecting previously unselected package pdfedit.
(Reading database ... 243246 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /tmp/tmp.wsQUAOPX4D ...
Unpacking pdfedit (0.4.5-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pdfedit:
 pdfedit depends on libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8-b); however:
  Package libqt3-mt is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package pdfedit (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pdfedit
```

Comment: PDFEdit seems to have lost support back in Ubuntu 12.10 - there is a launchpad site for the application, but the last update was October 2011.  I think you may need to look for a different solution.

Comment: Thanks Charles, Already did and have installed pdfmod. used it and worked fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

try executing

`FILE='mktemp'; wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt-x11-free/libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb -qO $FILE && sudo dpkg -i $FILE; rm $FILE`

then try installing pdfedit again

Comment: HI, After typing sudo apt-get install libqt3-mt - and under is what it gives me back:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libqt3-mt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libqt3-mt' has no installation candidate

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install pdfedit` and report back the results

Comment: Hi Younes this is what comes on the screen:

sudo apt-get install pdfedit
[sudo] password for jocondo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pdfedit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pdfedit' has no installation candidate
 Thanks

Comment: Younes, Thanks for your efforts.

I read through the ubuntu guide at http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Trusty#PDF_Toolkit_.28PDF_file_management.29.

I found another app pdfmod. I tried installing it and found that it suits my purpose in modifying the pages of a pdf file.

Again thanks for your time.

Comment: welcome anytime